# Checking multiple truthy value in If statement without logical AND operator

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, logical-operators

Logical `&&` operator returns true if both or all operands are true:

```
if (a && b) console.log("Hello");
```

But today I came across checking for the truthy values in if statement without `&&` logical operator:

```
if ((a, b)) console.log("Hello");
```

So I'd like to ask, is this also valid way of checking for the truthy values? Also can you please share your thoughts on how is this working?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't do what you think it does, it only checks `b`.

Comment: So, it checks only the last operand?

Comment: [Yep](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).